# When sending back slash with the data in Url for @PathParam, it's taking as a forward slash

Tags: java, spring-boot

When sending back slash with the data in Url for @PathParam, it's taking as a forward slash.

ex:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/'helloe\\'
```

getting the above value as `'helloe//'`.

Actually, what's happening is , I am trying to trigger the URL which has a value with back slash `\`, when I trigger the URL, it comes to my rest end point and the value in URL should be captured in my @PathParam variable.

But when I trigger the URL, the value from the URL which has back slash `\` is converted to `/` slash and stored in @PathParam variable. So don't know why it's converting from `\` back slash to `/` forward slash when URL is triggered.

Comment: Did you try encoding the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` instead of `\`

```
System.out.println("\\"); -> \
```

Answer (score 0):

You should URLEncode the PathParam in the url:

```
String encode = URLEncoder.encode("helloe\\", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(encode);
```

Output:

```
helloe%5C
```

So this would give following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/helloe%5C
```